# fontFamily "$text-font-family" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: reactjs, validation, expo

This is react expo project and the error appeared when using react-native-form-validation for validation.

```
<Input
    value={fullName}
    label="Full Name"
    captionTextStyle={styles.captionTextStyle}
    caption={errors.fullName.length > 0 && errors.fullName}
    status={errors.fullName.length > 0 ? "danger" : ""}
    onChangeText={value => this.handleChange("fullName", value)}
/>
```

This is one part of validation Input using react-native-ui-kitten.

The error runs because all the texts in input like labels and inputting texts.

I didn't find the reason why this error happened.

Comment: You have not loaded `fonts` correctly.

Comment: So you mean use the Font.loadAsync?
Please share me some examples.

Comment: is there anywhere in your code where you used `fontFamily : "Some font name"`?...That font has not been loaded correclty

Comment: I got the error. See, `react-native-ui-kitten` uses `open-sans` as their default font so you need to install it manually as it is not a system font. Check my answer.

Comment: So you mean install the font directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same error. reason is ui-kitten library use "OpenSans-Regular".
see: [ui-kitten-documentation](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/branding#typography)

you can add the .ttf of [OpenSans-Regular](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans#standard-styles) font to assets folder.

then load the font to the system via expo-font.
see: [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firsly, run `npm i expo-font`

Then, run `npm i @expo-google-fonts/open-sans`

Then, run `npm i expo-app-loading`

Then in your project folder create a file called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located.

in `hooks` folder create a file called `useFonts.js` and inside that paste this code

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import {
  OpenSans_300Light,
  OpenSans_300Light_Italic,
  OpenSans_400Regular,
  OpenSans_400Regular_Italic,
  OpenSans_600SemiBold,
  OpenSans_600SemiBold_Italic,
  OpenSans_700Bold,
  OpenSans_700Bold_Italic,
  OpenSans_800ExtraBold,
  OpenSans_800ExtraBold_Italic,
} from '@expo-google-fonts/open-sans';

const useFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    OpenSans_300Light,
    OpenSans_300Light_Italic,
    OpenSans_400Regular,
    OpenSans_400Regular_Italic,
    OpenSans_600SemiBold,
    OpenSans_600SemiBold_Italic,
    OpenSans_700Bold,
    OpenSans_700Bold_Italic,
    OpenSans_800ExtraBold,
    OpenSans_800ExtraBold_Italic,
  });
};

export default useFonts;
```

and in your `App.js`, write like this

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import useFonts from './hooks/useFonts';

export default function RegisterScreen(props) {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFontsAndRestoreToken = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFontsAndRestoreToken}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={() => {}}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'OpenSans_400Regular' }}>Text Example</Text>
      <Text>Normal Text</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```